# Open Vuetify v-dialog on mouseleave

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to open a v-dialog when the user is leaving the window.

I have implemented :

```
<v-dialog v-model="showPopinAlert">
<v-card>alert</v-card>
</v-dialog>
```

and in the script I have the event in the mounted() :

```
data () {
    return {
      showPopinAlert : false
    }
  },
mounted () {
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseleave', function (event) {
      if (event.clientY <= 0 || event.clientX <= 0 || (event.clientX >= window.innerWidth || event.clientY >= window.innerHeight)) {
        this.showPopinAlert = true
        console.log('leaving')       
      }
    })
  },
```

When the cursor is leaving the body I have the trace in the console, but the v-dialog isn't showing up. I've tried to force the refresh with a :key or a v-if but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to preserve the `this` context:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event) => {
  if (event.clientY <= 0 || event.clientX <= 0 || (event.clientX >= window.innerWidth || event.clientY >= window.innerHeight)) {
    this.showPopinAlert = true
    console.log('leaving')       
  }
})
```

Otherwise the callback function injects its own `this`